# Canvas multiple Text draw performance

Tags: performance, canvas, dart

Is there a way of drawing efficiently multiple characters individually at some reasonable FPS on Canvas in Dart?

I am rendering an array of characters with different colors, background rectangles, etc and it runs smoothly only if the "resolution of characters" is max 40x40.

This is the drawing method:

```dart
static draw(CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx, CanvasRenderingContext2D ctxUnvisible) {

  for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < chars[0].length; j++) {
      ctxUnvisible.fillRect(i*offX, j*offY, (i+1)*offX, (j+1)*offY);
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < chars[0].length; j++) {
      ctxUnvisible.fillStyle = charArray[i][j].color;
      ctxUnvisible.fillText(charArray[i][j].char, i*offX, j*offY);
    }
  }
  ctx.drawImage(ctxUnvisible.canvas, 0, 0);
}
```

The first double loop renders background rectangles as "text background" and the second draws the characters itself. This unfornately doesn't work for larger number of characters. Is there some more efficient way of drawing it? I am already drawing to unvisible canvas and then copying it to the visible one, but that's still not enough.

Comment: Have you tried it only in Dartium or also in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: Compiling it to JS or running it in Dartium results in approximately same performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In system all single char is prerendered ( I've heard it, not confirmed. ). You can make lazy initialized Map of CanvasElements and draw every character like image.
Example:

```dart
CanvasElement precompiled_a = new CanvasElement(width:20, height:20);
CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx = precompiled_a.context2D;
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillText("a", 10, 10);
CanvasElement c = querySelector("canvas");
c.context2D.drawImage(precompiled_a, 2, 2);
```

Comment: That sounds promising. Any idea how?

Comment: Do you mean http://simonsarris.com/blog/322-canvas-drawtext-considered-harmful? It is similar to the code in the question but it prerenders single chars and keeps them to just copy them from one canvas to the other when needed (I just took a brief look).

Comment: Example added to another answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, when having a color variations + all the characters, the map would be huge! (Like really huge)

Comment: You need 4 bytes on pixel in RAM. Lookup time don't change much with growing map. Sou if you have 20 * 20px per char, so you need 1600 bytes on char ... 1000 variations should take 1.6MB in RAM

Comment: Ok. When taken into account all the colors (#FFFFFF), which is 16777215 and roughly 100 00 chars, it's 167772150 MB of RAM. (I hope my calculations are correct - no guarantee.)

Comment: ... try DivX or mp4 :-)

Comment: I was thinking about WebGL, but I have no idea how that'd work with text.

Comment: Ok, I came across an idea. How about not making an initial HashMap, but each draw call trying to look up in the HashMap and if it does not exist, create a cache. This way, it'll be RAM friendly and still eficient. I'll accept your anwser anyway, though.. :)

Comment: I've heard of graphic chip accelerated text rendering in Internet Explorer 11, but I don't think there will this possibility in WebGL. In WebGL you wil render text in the same way, but on some texture in 3D.